# To sort an ArrayList of strings using an sorted ArrayList of integers

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists. One with integer values and the other list has string. I must use custom sort in comparator interface to sort the integer ArrayList so that the string ArrayList gets sorted based on it. How do I change the following code to find the solution using Comparator.

```
import java.util.*;

class ListTask
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    List<String> l2 = new ArrayList();
    List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean err = false;
    int n;
    do
    {
      try
      {
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of values to be entered");
        //to find the length of 2 lists l1 and l2
        n= in.nextInt();
        //add values to l1
        System.out.println("Please enter the id ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
          l1.add(in.nextInt());
          //to add values to l2
          System.out.println("Please enter the name");
          for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
          {
            l2.add(in.next());
            err = false;
          }
        }
      } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
      }
    } while(err);

    //code to sort list l2 based on the list l1
    for(int i=0;i<l1.size();i++)
    {
      for(int j=i+1;j<l1.size();j++)
      {
        if((l1.get(i)) > (l1.get(j)))
        {
          Collections.swap(l1, i, j);
          Collections.swap(l2, i, j);
        }
      }
    }
    //displays the sorted values
    display(l1, l2);
  }

  public static void display(List l1, List l2)
  {
    System.out.println("The sorted List is");
    for(int i=0;i<l1.size();i++)
    {
      System.out.println("Id= "+ l1.get(i) + " Name= " + l2.get(i));
    }
  } 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to:

1. Create a custom object which has 2 fields: `Id` and `Name`. Let us call this object `User`.
2. Replace `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` with `List<User>`.
3. When user enters the data, instead of adding to two lists, construct a new `User` object and add it to the list created in step 2.
4. Make your `User` class implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. (`implements Comparable<User>`).
5. In your `compareTo` method override compare the the `Id` of the current object with the one you are provided.
6. Call [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) on the `List<User>`.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to use a `TreeMap<Integer, String>`? When you add to the map it will automatically be sorted by the Key.

Comment: That would work, but I suppose that your solution would go beyond the scope of this problem, which I suppose is an assignment.

Comment: Surely recreating a TreeSet manually using user defined classes would be a bit redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

```
List<Pair<Integer, String>> l1l2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) { // I asume that l2 has the same length as l1
        l1l2.add(new Pair<>(l1.get(i), l2.get(i)));
    }
    Collections.sort(l1l2, Comparator.comparing(Pair::getKey));
```

Instead of `Pair` you can also make your own class which has 2 fields.

to print out the sorted List change your display Method:

```
public static void display(List<Pair<Integer, String>> l1l2) {

    System.out.println("The sorted List is");
    for (int i = 0; i < l1l2.size(); i++)
        System.out.println("Id= " + l1l2.get(i).getKey() + " Name= " + l1l2.get(i).getValue());

}
```

you have to think about:

- do you really need to enter the inputs in 2 divided stepps (first all IDs than the Names? ... why not ID,name,ID,name, and so on. In that case you wouldn't need the 2 Lists)
- what should happen if there are 2 Items with the same id?